# How do I make a command that triggers even though the command is followed by other words?

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to make a command for my Discord bot which the bot replies regardless if the user says some other text inside the command triggering message, like an 8ball command. Is this possible? If you don't know what I mean, here's an example

```
if ("message.content === "*8ball");
 message.channel.send(variablename)
```

`User: *8ball am i cool`

`Bot:  | yes`

I'm guessing I have to change `message.content` to something different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
client.on("message", (message) => {
    const prefix = "-";
    const arguments = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    const commandName = arguments.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix) && commandName == "8ball") {
        message.channel.send("reply here");
    };
});
```